# Java Null Pointer Exception in Worker Class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at Volume.<init>(Volume.java:25)
at VolumeDriver.main(VolumeDriver.java:6)
```

I get the above errors when trying to run my program. My program is not complete but I just want to check what my window looks like so I can make sure it looks correct.
This is my worker class for right now

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Volume extends JFrame
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel topPanel;
private JPanel bottomPanel;
private JPanel rightPanel;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JLabel message;
private final int width = 500;
private final int height = 400;

public Volume()
{
    setTitle("Sphere and Box Volumes");
    setSize(width,height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    BuildTopPanel();
    getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    BuildBotPanel();
    getContentPane().add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    BuildRightPanel();
    getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    BuildMainPanel();

    setVisible(true);
}
private void BuildTopPanel()
    {
        topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JTextField reqVolume = new JTextField(8);
        message = new JLabel("Enter the required amount of volume:");
        topPanel.add(message);
        topPanel.add(reqVolume);
    }
private void BuildBotPanel()
    {
        bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JButton intialQuant = new JButton("Set Initial Quantities");
        intialQuant.setActionCommand("I");
        intialQuant.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        JButton calcVolume = new JButton("Calculate Volumes");
        calcVolume.setActionCommand("V");
        calcVolume.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        JButton close = new JButton("Close");
        close.setActionCommand("C");
        close.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        bottomPanel.add(intialQuant);
        bottomPanel.add(calcVolume);
        bottomPanel.add(close);
    }
private void BuildRightPanel()
{
    rightPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
private void BuildMainPanel()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }
 }
}
```

This is my driver class

```
public class VolumeDriver 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Volume frame = new Volume();
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `topPanel` is `null`. You might want to use a debugger and figure out. Or move `BuildTopPanel();` one line up. Also note that usually java method name starts with a lowercase letter

Comment: You might want to use a lower case on the first character of your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Uh oh! topPanel is not initialized!
BuildTopPanel();
```

You try to add your `topPanel` before its initialization in the `BuildTopPanel()` method, so it will obviously lead to a NPE!

This is also the case for your other build methods. Be sure to actually initialize and build your GUI elements before using them or adding them to your window!

For instance:

```
// Initialize GUI elements first:
BuildTopPanel();
BuildBotPanel();
BuildRightPanel();
BuildMainPanel();
// Then add the GUI elements to the window:
getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
getContentPane().add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize the component before you add it to panel. see the documents as below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29

That means you need call BuildMainPanel() before getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

The same with the other components.